# OK to swap a SATA DVD for a SATA HD?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, sata

I'm considering picking up a used Lenovo M58 in its small form factor case to build a linux (ubuntu) server. The M58 has a standard 3.5-inch bay for an internal SATA HD and a 5.25-inch half-height bay for an external SATA DVD, but no free internal bay for a second internal drive (thus the small form factor). Since I don't have a need for the DVD player, I'm considering removing it and using its bay for a second internal HD.

Could it be this simple, or am I taking on a world of hurt? I'm not looking for a hardware project here, so if the DVD and HD are not interchangeable, I'll look for a different box that has a free internal bay.

Comment: It should be fine. One of my colleagues did similar swap on a lenovo but with a battery :D

Comment: [You just need some 3.5 to 5.25 rail adapters](http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Universal-Mounting-Bracket-BRACKET/dp/B0001UZQWG) to mount the drive

Comment: @Moab, you should write that in slightly longer form as an answer, and buttonsrtoys should accept it.

Comment: And add that many drives sold in "retail kits" include those adapters.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan, never got them in all the drives I have ever purchased, 100+ retail drives.

Comment: @Moab interesting. I have a large box full of the things - that came with "retail kit" drives. Now that you mention it, though, I haven't seen them in a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mount a 3.5 drive in a 5.25 space if you use adapters.

[image]

[Example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0001UZQWG)

Comment: Ended up with a six y.o. HP DC7900 (small form factor), so same issue. Rails worked great except that they were maybe 1/16" too narrow for some reason but adding a couple washers made them fit perfectly. Put in my two 3TB drives. Had to update the BIOS so it could recognize the size (initially registered as 800GB before the update). Very happy with the end product.